# jenkins + remote powershell script

Tags: jenkins

I have a windows build server A ,another server B it has installed weblogic application server ..

once i trigger job from A it will give Build number and release number (4.2.3-100)

my work is i have to pass this value to B server, it has one file demo.text ,4.2.3-100 value should update in the demo.txt file
i have written one powershell script and kept in B server am triggering that script from A server jenkins using psexec

$file1="C:\demo.txt"

$oldText=Get-Content $file1 | select -Index 14
$b = Get-Date
Write-Output "Backups complete at $b"

Get-Content "C:\demo.txt" | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "$oldText",$($env:BLD_NUMBER)-$($env:BUILD_NUMBER)-$b" } | Set-Content "C:\demo.txt" -Force

Comment: suppose if i keep that demo.txt file in server A and run it works ..but when i keep that file in server B and try to update from jenkins it will not take that build number and release number please help me

Comment: Where have you installed Jenkins?

Comment: server A ,this is windows server

Comment: I would suggest you install a Jenkins slave of Server A in server B and try to execute the script in server B using a Jenkns job.

Comment: server B is a QA server ,it has weblogic application server...our goal is to automate nightly build deployment ..for that, i need to change server B demo.txt file from server A (remotely)

Comment: jenkins from server A should trigger @ mng 3 AM ..it should take .ear and copy to server B and modify the demo.txt and start the weblogic server

Comment: Okay. Let me get this straight, you have a Jenkins installed in server A and retrieving the build number there and then you need to pass into `demo.txt` in server B. So, it is best to connect server B to server A using a salve in my opinion.

Comment: server A job we are building using 4.3 weblogic slave,
all builds are stored in 4.3 target,

server B is //123.34.56./7001 weblogic server ,

my goal

i need to stop weblogic server from jenkins A,
i have to copy .ear to server B is //123.34.56./7001 weblogic server,
i have to copy properties from 4.3 weblogic slave to //123.34.56./7001 weblogic server,
i have to modify demo,.text of server B from server A remotley,it should update build number and release number,

Comment: Imp--

i tried to copy demo.txt and keep in my 4.3 weblogic slave and tried to run it is passing build number and release number to the demo.txt .

when i keep demo.txt in //123.34.56./7001 weblogic server ,treid to pass build number and release number from 4.3 weblogic slave it is not updating in demo.txt.